# Group by every n rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Given a MySql table, is there a way to use Group By to group every n rows, in the same way a Group By normally would?

Say we have rows like:

- A, 12
- B, 14
- C, 20
- D, 78
- E, 90
- F, 65

I want Group By n = 2 to return

- A, 12
- C, 20
- E, 90

Since each bucket contains 2 rows, like a normal Group By.

After grouping like this, I am going to run another query that will return say, the sum of all the second column in every group, so the end result rows would look like:

| Group | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 98 |
| 3 | 155 |

Comment: which version of mysql you are in?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.24 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL) @JorgeCampos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first query, you may use `ROW_NUMBER` with the modulus:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) % 2 rem
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, val
FROM cte
WHERE rem = 0;
```

### Demo

For the second query, we can use a similar approach with integer division

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) / 2) dvd
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT dvd + 1 AS grp, SUM(val) AS val_sum
FROM cte
GROUP BY dvd;
```

### Demo